# How to change from character to date format?

Tags: r, date

For my dataset, the Date variable has dates in the format of this example: 19-Feb-03
I want to change the above character format dates in the column to a Date format. (As I have to do time series analysis later on)

I tried using the as.Date() method but it didn't work.

Comment: You can use `lubridate::dmy()` or you can specify a format string (assuming your locale is English) `as.Date(your_data$your_column, format = "%d-%b-%y")`. The format string keys are documented at `?strftime`.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- '19-Feb-03'

lubridate::ymd(x)

"2019-02-03"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether 19 is year or day. You can try lubridate package

```
x<-"19-Feb-03"

library(lubridate)

ymd(x)
dmy(x)
```